# Gshare branch predictor for gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to use `Gshare` in gem5. I have found the source code and instructions [here](https://github.com/QawsQAER/gem5branchPredictor). Unfortunately, the `GshareBP` option didn’t appeared on gem5’s branch predictor list.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is generated from the Python classes. The author forgot to add the Python declarations of the parameter classes, so you will have to do that yourself.

For example, `GShareBP` needs the parameters `localPredictorSize` and `localCtrBits`, so you will need to add the following class `src/cpu/pred/BranchPredictor.py` (this is just an example; I don't know the actual values of the parameters):

```
class GShareBP(BranchPredictor):
    type = 'GShareBP'
    cxx_class = 'GShareBP'
    cxx_header = "cpu/pred/gshare.hh"

    localPredictorSize = Param.Unsigned(2048, "Size of local predictor")
    localCtrBits = Param.Unsigned(2, "Bits per counter")
```

You will also need to inform that gshare.cc must be compiled (in `src/cpu/pred/SConscript`):

```
Source('gshare.cc')
```

You will face a lot of errors after doing that; that code was written for 2014's gem5.

Things you may also need to do:

- Add the following to gshare.cc `#include "params/GShareBP.hh"`
- Add `typedef GShareBPParams Params;` to gshare.hh
- Rename `SatCounter` as `SatCounter8`

For more information, you may find the book [Learning gem5](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part2/parameters.html) helpful